# How sum a range column in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
J    
1    
2    
3
```

This is the code:

```
function sumsald () {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
   var s1 = ss.getSheetByName ("rendPendForm");
   var dataRange = s1.getDataRange ();
   var lastrow = dataRange.getLastRow ();
   var values = s1.getRange (2.10, lastrow, 1) .getValues ();
        var sum = 0;           
        for (var i = 0; i <values.length; i ++) {
            result = values [i] [10] + sum;
            Logger.log (result);
     }
     s1.getRange (i + 1, 10) .setValue (result);
  }
```

Result script = `# NUM!`
`Logger.log` = `NaN`

6 expected

Thanks, Luis.

Comment: ``values[i][0]``

Comment: `[i][10]` accesses the 11th column of each row.

Comment: With values [i] [0]
Script result set.Value blank
Logger.log 1 0 / 2 0 / 3 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if in the example the `J` is the column name or value on the first row. Anyway, to get values starting from first row in column J all the way to row on index `lastrow`:

```
var values = s1.getRange (1, 10, lastrow, 1) .getValues ();
```

In addition, when adding up the numbers its good to ignore non-number values. For example if you sum a string from a header row and a number from row below you get a concatenated string of the two in Javascript/GoogleScript, instead of an error or ignoring the string. This appends to the sum only if `values[i][0]` contains a number (otherwise adds `0` to the sum i.e. does nothing):

```
result += typeof values[i][0] == 'number' ? values[i][0] : 0;
```

Below full example:

```
function sumsald () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName ("rendPendForm");
  var dataRange = s1.getDataRange ();
  var lastrow = dataRange.getLastRow ();
  var values = s1.getRange (1, 10, lastrow, 1) .getValues ();
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <values.length; i ++) {
    result += typeof values[i][0] == 'number' ? values[i][0] : 0;
    Logger.log (result);
  }
  s1.getRange (i + 1, 10) .setValue (result);
}
```

Comment: J is the column, the script gives the expected result, excuse the English.
Health for yours and for you @Joonas
Thank you,
Luis.

Comment: Thanks you jonas!!